# Period calculation for elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, hodge-theory

In the paper "[Hodge cycles on Abelian Varieties](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/Deligne82.pdf)" (Proposition 1.5), Deligne proves the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ of dimension $n$. Let $Z \subset X$ be a subvariety of dimension $r$. Let $\omega$ be a $C^{\infty} \, 2r$-form on $X(\mathbf{C})$ whose class $[\omega] \in H^{2n}_{dR}(X/\mathbf{C})$ belongs to $H^{2n}_{dR}(X/\overline{\mathbf{Q}})$. Then
> $$\int_Z \omega \in (2\pi i)^r \overline{\mathbf{Q}}^{\times}.$$

I have an example that I cannot make sense of. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$, and set $X=Z=E$. Then $\omega_E$ is the invariant differential, then $\omega = \omega_E \wedge \overline{\omega_E}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ $2$-form on $E(\mathbf{C})$. Therefore, the theorem would imply that
$$\int_{E(\mathbf{C})} \omega_E \wedge \overline{\omega_E} \in (2\pi i) \overline{\mathbf{Q}}^{\times}.$$
But this seems obviously wrong, because the above integral should equal an integer times $2\pi i \langle f,f \rangle$, where $f$ is the modular form attached to $E$, and I'm pretty that $\langle f,f \rangle$ is transcendental. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think that $\overline{\omega_E}$ does not belong to $H^1_{\mathrm{dR}}(E/{\mathbf{Q}})$. The latter space is stable under $\omega \mapsto c^*(\overline{\omega})$ (with $c$ the complex conjugation), but not under the involution $\omega \mapsto \overline{\omega}$. You can consider instead $\frac{dx}{y} \wedge x \frac{dx}{y}$ whose integral over $E(\mathbf{C})$ gives you $2\pi i$ (the Legendre relation).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault thank you! That clears up my confusion.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault A follow-up question, isn't the form $\frac{dx}{y} \wedge x \frac{dx}{y} = 0$ since $dx \wedge dx = 0$?

Comment: Sorry, this means the cup-product $H^1_{\mathrm{dR}} \times H^1_{\mathrm{dR}} \to H^2_{\mathrm{dR}}$. In this situation it does not behave like the exterior product of differential forms. Here $(\frac{dx}{y},x\frac{dx}{y})$ is a basis of $H^1_{\mathrm{dR}}$. Note the second form is not regular at infinity, but has no residue and still defines an element of $H^1_{\mathrm{dR}}$.